# Spring Boot Security: Why Strict-Transport-Security header is not including preload; when preload set to true

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have a spring boot application where i have added WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
I want to have the response header strict-transport-security: max-age=16000000; includeSubDomains; preload;
I have added the below code to the SecurityConfig as:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  
    http.headers(headers ->
        headers.httpStrictTransportSecurity(hstsConfig -> {
          hstsConfig.preload(true);
          hstsConfig.includeSubDomains(true);
          hstsConfig.maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);
        })
            .contentSecurityPolicy(contentSecurityPolicy ->
                contentSecurityPolicy
                    .policyDirectives("script-src 'self'")
            )
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-My-Custom-Header","myvalue"))
    );

    http.csrf().disable();
  }
```

The response header is not adding the "preload;" instead it looks like:

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

Can someone please help me to understand what am I missing here?

Spring Security Config: v5.4.6

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything in the configuration that would cause `preload` to be missing. Is it possible that the `strict-transport-security` is being written somewhere else in the code? You can try debugging the `writeHeaders` method in  `HstsHeaderWriter` to find out why the header is being set incorrectly.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, this happens only when the microservice is accessed through Kong API Gateway. Could that be an issue? Is Kong caching the headers?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Kong works. If possible, see what happens without the API gateway, to narrow down the issue. Then post a new question where someone more familiar with Kong may be able to help.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, sure I will do that. Thanks